# Landscape RestAPI error - Invalid API version

Tags: landscape

When using Postman to try and access Landscape 19.10's API, I receive an "Invalid API version" result:

Postman output:
[image: Postman output]

Steps to build the API request:
[image: Steps to build the API request]

Does anyone know how to find out the API version that 19.10 is using, as I am hoping that I can simply add the API version to step 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to resolve this issue by creating a URL-encoded value from the Base64 value.

We intend to use Powershell to perform all of these different types of encoding automatically, once we have identified which calls to make to gather all required data about devices and the hardware and software that is installed on them.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from the [documentation](https://ubuntu.com/landscape/docs/low-level-http-requests)

> The version of the API, 2011-08-01 being the current one

You might want to read that documentation carefully as your query seems to miss some parameters (signature method, version and timestamp). Also, your parameters need to be sorted.